# How to get dataframe for a .dat file?

Tags: dataframe

I'm trying to perform logistic regression on data from a .dat file. First I formed the dataframe and tried calling columns from it but I get the following error.

```
data=pd.read_csv('wells.dat')

frame=DataFrame(data)

frame.head()

frame['arsenic'].head()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'arsenic'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-5eede9a7b2ac> in <module>
     18 frame.head()
     19 
---> 20 frame['arsenic'].head()
     21 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'arsenic'
```

Is it because it's a .dat file and not .csv? This is what the dataframe looks like:
[image]

Comment: What's the content of `well.dat`?

Comment: I included a picture of the dataframe at the bottom of post

Comment: `read_csv()` use `,` as column delimiter by default. I need to see the raw content of your `well.dat` to ensure what's the delimiter of your file.